# PHP local scope block

Tags: php, scope

Is there a way to make a local scope in PHP7, simpler than the following?

```
$a = 1;

(function(){
  $a = 2;
  print("inside: $a\n");   
})();

print("outside: $a\n");
```

Outputs :

```
inside: 2
outside: 1
```

Comment: your code appear to contain syntax errors, being `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('` and what do you mean by "simpler"? can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, This code seems to work under PHP 7.0.18, but I never seen this before. Looks like javascript...

Comment: For instance in C++, you can declare local variables inside brackets, and they are automatically destroyed at the end of the scope.

Comment: @Syscall Yeah, I actually had that same thought and almost added that to my comment, wondering if their server ran under 7.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP: the global scope and the local function scope (one for each function call).

The short answer to your question is: **No**.